# Nutch doesn't crawls all urls

Tags: solr, web-crawler, nutch

I am using Nutch for web crawling with crawl script using the command

```
bin/crawl -s urls crawl 3
```

In my portal, for each page, there should be 2 versions available. If I have a page with link `example.com/docs`, there should be 2 versions as `example.com/docs?v=1` and `example.com/docs?v=2` for all pages and the content will be different. When I run the Nutch crawl script, it fetches only one version of documents.

How can I resolve that?

Comment: check nutch plugin url-normalizer and see any trimming happening on query params ...

Comment: or check in plugin-includes conf of nutch whether ***queryparam-normalizer** is included r not ... if included please go ahead and remove it.